# Echo line (relace to jquery) shows up in browser

Tags: php, jquery

Got the exact same problem as @Zain explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824670/my-wordpress-website-is-slow-due-to-a-line-in-init-php/29428993).
I tried the following code:

```
efunction wp_func_jquery() {
  // Get jQuery from Google CDN
  echo "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js";
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery');
```

The error disappeared, and the page loads correctly. But still at the very end of the page appears the following row:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js

You can [check it out here, to see what I mean.](http://relaxwithmusic.co.nf/) 
How can I get rid of this problem?
Thanks in advance,
Pietro

Comment: for wordpress i sugest you use the standard way of handeling scrips with wp_enqueue_script   https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that, u forget about `<script>` tag

```
efunction wp_func_jquery() {
  // Get jQuery from Google CDN
  echo "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_func_jquery');
```

Comment: @PietroGirardi glad for u, don't forget to approve ans) to improving SO)